# LINQ: How to do JOIN using the linq extension method style on multiple fields?

Tags: linq, join, field

In the Join below, I'd like to use multiple fields to do the join rather than just one field.

```
var join = group.Join(procSums, g => g.DeptID, ps => ps.key.deptID, (g, ps)...
```

All examples Ive found use the query style to do this and I can't translate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You just have to Join based on new anonymous objects:

```
// ClasID is a placeholder, it could be any property you'd like
var join = group.Join(procSums,
                      g => new { g.DeptID, g.UnitLoc, g.Proc },
                      ps => new 
                            { 
                              DeptID = ps.key.deptID, 
                              UnitLoc = ps.key.unitLoc,
                              Proc = ps.key.procName 
                            },
                      (g, ps) => new { g, ps });
```

Comment: OK, here it is `var join = group.Join(procSums, g => new { g.DeptID, g.UnitLoc, g.Proc },
                                                ps => new { ps.key.deptID, ps.key.unitLoc, ps.key.procName }, (g, ps) => new
                                                {
                                                    g,
                                                    ps
                                                });` But it has an error saying that Type Args cannot be inferred. The types are the same, they match exactly.

Comment: @user259286 - The names of the properties in the anonymous types (as well as their types) must match exactly. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass lambda expressions that create anonymous types with the fields.
For example:

```
group.Join(procSums, g => new { g.DeptID, g.OtherField }, ps => new { ps.key.deptID, ps.key.OtherField }, ...)
```

The anonymous types must match exactly.