# Using Join to get the updated Table Linq Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Trying joining using Linq. What should I use? Left join or right join?

```
    FIRST LIST                                 SECOND LIST

APPLICANT_ID|Applicant_Name| NOTES | |APPLICANT_ID|Applicant_Name  | NOTES |
      1     |  RAY HEAVENS | Note1 | |    2       |  BEN TULFO     | NoteA 
      2     |  BEN TULFO   | Note2 | |    3       |  ERNIE BARON   | NoteB 
      3     |  ERNIE BARON | Note3 | | 
      4     |   SUPERMAN   | Note4 | |
      5     |  MARK LAPID  | Note5 | |
```

Desired output:

```
APPLICANT_ID | Applicant_Name |   NOTES 
-------------+----------------+---------
      1      |   RAY HEAVENS  |  Note1
      2      |   BEN TULFO    |  NoteA
      3      |   ERNIE BARON  |  NoteB
      4      |   SUPERMAN     |  Note4
      5      |   MARK LAPID   |  Note5
```

This is my code in my controller:

```
 var applicantList = (from a in db.Profiles 
                      where a.isDeleted == false
                      select a ).ToList();

 var GetNewNotes = (from a in db.ProfilesNotes 
                    where a.isDeleted == false
                    select a).ToList();

 var lst = (from lst1 in applicantList 
            where !GetNewNotes.Any(x => x.APPLICANT_ID == lst1.APPLICANT_ID )
            select lst1).ToList();

ViewBag.updatedNotes = lst;
```

I hope someone can recommend me what to use or what to do.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is an odd structure to map. Structurally it looks like a 1-to-0..1, but in concept it looks like it should be 1-to-many. For a 1-to-many I'd be expecting a table structure more like:

**Applicant** ( ApplicantId | Name )

**ApplicantNote** ( ApplicantNoteId | ApplicantId | Note )

This would be mapped in EF something like:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicantNote> { get; set; } = new List<ApplicantNote>();
}

public class ApplicantNote
{
    public int ApplicantNoteId { get; set; }
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicantConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Applicant>
{
    public ApplicantConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Applicant");
        HasKey(x => x.ApplicantId);

        HasMany(x => x.ApplicantNotes)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Applicant)
            .Map(x => x.MapKey("ApplicantId"));
    }
}
public class ApplicantNoteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ApplicantNote>
{
    public ApplicantNoteConfig()
    {
        ToTable("ApplicantNote");
        HasKey(x => x.ApplicantNoteId);
    }
}
```

What you have is more like an Applicant table that contains a note, but then there is an additional table that can hold a single, additional extra note.

**Applicant** ( ApplicantId | Name | Note )

**ExtraApplicantNote** ( ApplicantId | Note )  // Name isn't required.

which in a 1-to-0..1 would look something like:

```
public class Applicant
{
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public ExtraApplicantNote ExtraApplicantNote { get; set; }
}

public class ExtraApplicantNote
{
    public int ApplicantId { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public virtual Applicant Applicant { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicantConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Applicant>
{
    public ApplicantConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Applicant");
        HasKey(x => x.ApplicantId);

        HasOptional(x => x.ExtraApplicantNote)
            .WithRequired(x => x.Applicant);
    }
}
public class ExtraApplicantNoteConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExtraApplicantNote>
{
    public ExtraApplicantNoteConfig()
    {
        ToTable("ExtraApplicantNote");
        HasKey(x => x.ApplicantId);
    }
}
```

This joins this extra applicant note record to the Applicant as an optional associated entity. When selecting as an entity graph:

```
var applicant = context.Applicants
    .Include(x => x.ExtraApplicantNote)
    .Single(x => x.ApplicantId == applicantId);
```

for example... then access the note(s) via `applicant.Note` and `applicant?.ExtraApplicantNote.Note` to account for the fact that an extra applicant note is optional.

To produce an output of all notes with their applicant details, a 1-to-many structure is far, far simpler to produce:

```
var notes = context.ApplicantNotes.Select(x => new 
  {
    x.Applicant.ApplicantId,
    x.Applicant.Name,
    x.Note
  }).ToList();
```

To do the same thing with a 1-to-0..1 is a fair bit more involved:

```
var notes = context.Applicants.Select(x => new 
  {
    x.ApplicantId,
    x.Name,
    x.Note
  }).Union(context.ExtraApplicantNotes.Select(x => new
  {
    x.ApplicantId,
    x.Applicant.Name,
    x.Note
  })).ToList();
```

This involves first pulling the notes from the first table, then using a union to join the same details from the optional records in the second table.

** Edit ** Sorry, I re-read the question and you want the 2nd table to override the first.

In this case, similar to above:

```
var notes = context.ExtraApplicantNotes.Select(x => new 
  {
    x.ApplicantId,
    x.Applicant.Name,
    x.Note
  }).Union(context.Applicants
  .Where(x => x.ExtraApplicant == null)      
  .Select(x => new
  { 
    x.ApplicantId,
    x.Name,
    x.Note
  })).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you sir for this explanation. I just want to ask what if `getNewnotes` has more values than the applicant list, eg. 3 list of applicants in `applicantlist` and 5 in `getnewnotes` . will it output 5 rows ?? or just the 3 on `applicantlist`?

Comment: That last edit is what I believe you are looking for, though with 2x unassociated tables with similar columns you should still be able to use the Union approach, and it would return back 5 rows. given the 3 IDs in applicant are also present in new notes.

Comment: sir thanks. Btw what do you mean by this ` .`Where(x => x.ExtraApplicant == null)   ` in your last edit

Comment: This would be setting up a relationship between the two entities, from the 0..1 configuration "` HasOptional(x => x.ExtraApplicantNote).WithRequired(x => x.Applicant);` Even though they are not directly related they share the PK so this relationship can be set up so that you get the 2nd table, and only 1st table records where they don't have a 2nd table association. (Use B plus any A that don't have a matching B)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for an *inner* join with `.Join()`:

```
var lst = applicantList.Join(GetNewNotes,
    (a) => a.APPLICANT_ID,
    (n) => n.APPLICANT_ID,
    (a, n) => return new
    {
        a.APPLICANT_ID,
        a.Applicant_Name,
        n.Notes
    });

/*
lst:
2 | BEN TULFO   | NoteA,
3 | ERNIE BARON | NoteB
*/
```

As a side note, is there any reason your second table contains `ApplicantName`?
Why not keep this in Applicant table only?

**EDIT:**
After re-reading the question, I realized that you need the unmatched entries from the left list
too. So, that should be `left outer join` instead, which you achieve with `.GroupJoin()` and `.SelectMany()`:

```
var lst = applicantList.GroupJoin(GetNewNotes,
    (a) => a.Id,
    (n) => n.Id,
    (a, n) => new
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Notes = a.Notes,
        ApplicantNotes = n
    })
    .SelectMany(
        g => g.ApplicantNotes.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (g, applicantNotes) => new
        {
            Id = g.Id,
            Name = g.Name,
            Notes = applicantNotes?.Notes ?? g.Notes
        });

/*
lst:
1 | RAY HEAVENS | Note1
2 | BEN TULFO   | NoteA
3 | ERNIE BARON | NoteB
4 | SUPERMAN    | Note4
5 | MARK LAPID  | Note5
*/
```

Comment: hahaha.. nice observation sir. i just added that column for more info

Comment: Well, as you can see, you can get that info by joining. :D

Comment: what if the getNewnotes has more values than the applicant list, eg. 3 list of applicants in `applicantlist` and 5 in `getnewnotes` . will it output 5 rows ?? or just the 3 on applicantlist?

Comment: sir what will be the output

Comment: Well it depends. Since this is an inner join, you discard the elements that do not match in both lists. If there are matching duplicate keys in the any of the  lists, and they match, those will be put to the result too.

Comment: Please see the edit for an idea of output. Also, I overlooked initially that you keep notes in the first table too. Similarly to names in the second table, do you need those? Why not keep all the notes in the second table, which should apparently be called `ApplicantNotes`?

Comment: sir after trying. there's an error that says `The type arguments for method Join cannot be inferred from the usage` and the variables a and n is not found same as the `return`

Comment: Sorry, I answered too hastily without understanding what your output should be. Please see the edit for that. As for the error, I'm not sure...Maybe this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044873/linq-lambda-join-error-cannot-be-inferred-from-the-usage?