# EntityFramework multiple where problems

Tags: c#, entity-framework, jqgrid

I am working with Entity Framework in my backend and using jqGrid in my frontend. My Grid looks like this:

[image: Filterrow]

if i am using one of these filters, my Grid is working perfect. 
For example:

Using Filter: "Erfasser"
[image: Using one Filter ("erfasser"]
Using Filter: "Land"
[image: Using one other Filter ("Land")]

Both Filters are working very fine, but in common I have the following result:

[image: Both Filters, but no Results]

I don't have a clue about the problem. Here is my Code:

```
    using (var db = new ProconContext())
    {
        // Paging für die Liste erstellen, da zuviele Datensätze, user sollte selber über die 
        // größe der Seite bestimmen können.
        var query = db.Belege.Join(db.Kunden, x => x.KundenNr, y => y.KundeId, (x, y) => new { Beleg = x, Kunde = y })
            .Select(x => new BelegKunden { Beleg = x.Beleg, Kunde = x.Kunde });

        db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

        query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.BelegTypId == belegArtNr);

        foreach (var param in parameters)
        {
            if (param.Key.Equals("BelegId"))
            {
                var belegId = Convert.ToInt32(param.Value);
                query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.BelegId == belegId);
            }

            if (param.Key == "Name")
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Name.Contains(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("Datum"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Datum.Equals(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("KundenNr"))
            {
                var kundenNr = Convert.ToInt32(param.Value);
                query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.KundenNr == kundenNr);
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("Land"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Land.ZweiBuchstabenIsoCode.Contains(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("PLZ"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Plz.Contains(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("Ort"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Ort.Contains(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("Erfasser"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.ErfasstVonUsername.Contains(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("Kommission"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.KopfKommission.Contains(param.Value));
            }

            if (param.Key.Equals("ErstePosition"))
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.ErsteRechnungsPosition.Contains(param.Value));
            }
        }

        var count = query.Count();

        var list = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Beleg.BelegDatum)
            .Skip(skip) // Wie viele soll er überspringen (die ersten x)
            .Take(take) // Wie viele soll er von da aus nehmen (nimm x)
            .ToList();

        list[0].AllRowsCount = count;
        return AppServerHelper.AppResponse(list);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    return AppServerHelper.AppResponse(new List<BelegKunden>());
}
```

On Runtime: The Result of count is working for one filter, but it wont work for 2.

I am using: 
jqGrid, EntityFramework

EDIT:

The auto generated code of Entity Framwework ist working fine on the server as SQL Statement. If i am copy the auto genereated code and execute them on the server i got the right results, for both filters.

EDIT:

My Models:

```
[Serializable]
public partial class Beleg
{
    [LocalizedDisplayName("BelegNr", ModelName = "tbWBI_Reklamationen")]
    public Int32 BelegId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Veraltet, BelegId ist nun der Primary Key
    /// </summary>                
    public Int32 AlteBelegId { get; set; }

    public Int16 BelegTypId { get; set; }
    public virtual BelegTyp BelegTyp { get; set; }

    public Int16? LetzterGedruckterBelegTypId { get; set; }
    public virtual BelegTyp LetzterGedruckterBelegTyp { get; set; }

    public Int32 KundenNr { get; set; }

    [LocalizedDisplayName("BelegDatum", ModelName = "tbVKBelege")]
    public DateTime BelegDatum { get; set; }


    public String KopfKommission { get; set; }
    public String ErsteRechnungsPosition { get; set; }
    public String ErfasstVonUsername { get; set; }
    public Double WarenwertBrutto { get; set; }
}
```

Config:

```
public class Beleg_Config : EntityTypeConfiguration<Beleg>
{
    public Beleg_Config()
    {
        ToTable("tbVKBelege");

        HasKey(a => a.BelegId);
        Property(a => a.BelegId)
            .HasColumnName("BelegNr")
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(a => a.AlteBelegId).HasColumnName("");

        Property(a => a.BelegTypId).HasColumnName("");

        Property(a => a.LetzterGedruckterBelegTypId).HasColumnName("");

        Property(a => a.ErsteRechnungsPosition).HasColumnName("");

        Property(a => a.ErfasstVonUsername).HasColumnName("");

        Property(a => a.WarenwertBrutto).HasColumnName("");


        HasRequired(b => b.BelegTyp).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.BelegTypId);

        HasOptional(b => b.LetzterGedruckterBelegTyp).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.LetzterGedruckterBelegTypId);            
    }
}
```

Config of Kunde:

```
public Kunde_Config()
{
    ToTable("tbKunden");

    HasKey(a => a.KundeId);
    Property(a => a.KundeId).HasColumnName("KundenNr").HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

    /*Property(a => a.KundeId)
        .HasColumnName("KundenNr")
        .
        .IsRequired();*/

    Property(a => a.AussendienstlerId).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.SpezialSbUserId).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.Name).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.Name2).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.Straße).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.TelefonNr).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.FaxNr).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.Website).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.KeyAccountManagerId).HasColumnName("");

    Property(a => a.KWFP).HasColumnName("KWFP");

    Property(a => a.IOHomeControl).HasColumnName("IOHomeControl");

    Property(a => a.TopPartner).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.ZahlungsbedingungId).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.EShop).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.EShopUsername).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.EShopPasswort).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.Quelle).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.Kommentar).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.Rabatt).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.IstBaanKunde).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.HatAltschulden).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.StandardLieferadressenNr).HasColumnName("");

    Property(x => x.IstWettbewerber).HasColumnName("");

    HasRequired(b => b.AußendienstMitarbeiter).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.k);
    HasRequired(b => b.Land).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.LandId);
    HasOptional(b => b.KeyAccountManager).WithMany().HasForeignKey(b => b.k);
    // HasOptional(x => x.Messedaten);
}
```

I deleted the "columnnames"in the config data as safety, sorry for that.

Comment: hi, try without the join.

Comment: Without the join its working fine, but i need some Informations from "Kunde".

Comment: Please post the models if you can for more understanding, but i believe the problem is in the Join you are making.

Comment: I will post the models as soon as i can.
Its a kind of strange but: if i am creating a "SQL View" on my SQL View and select the View with my wheres, i´ve got the same Problem.

Comment: KundenNr == KundenId the primary key of Kunden table ?

Comment: i think you dont need the select after the join.

Comment: in your view you need all columns of both tables ? if not the join is not wath you want, join is used to create a new "table" with a few columns of both tables.

Comment: Yeah, KundenNr is the primary key.

I need to join the kunde because i need the informations for my frontend, but not all columns

Answer (score 1):

I believe i got your problem, when you are making the join you are creating an anonymous type in a wrong fashion, do this way:

```
var query = db.Beleg.Join(
                db.Kunden,
                x => new { x.KundenNr }, //the outer selector, the foreing key to Kunden
                y => new { y.KundeId }, //the inner selector, the primary key in Kunde, this will match x.KundenNr == y.KundenId
                (x,y) => new { BelegNr = x.BelegId , BelegDatum = x.BelegDatum, Name = y.Name .....}); //here you select the columns(fields) in each table, and construct the new anonymous object with the fields that you need in each table
```

Here are some links that will help you to more understanding

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

[LINQ: How to do JOIN using the linq extension method style on multiple fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808116/linq-how-to-do-join-using-the-linq-extension-method-style-on-multiple-fields)

I was analazing and in your case you dont need a join, a join is used to select a few fields of each table you are joining, but here you are keeping the two entires tables. My advice is use simple where clause.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

well first of all: Thanks to emcas88 for you time and help!

I solved the Problem, with your idea: 
Selecting only the fields AND:

```
var query = db.Beleg.Join(
                db.Kunden,
                x => new { x.KundenNr }, //the outer selector, the foreing key to Kunden
                y => new { y.KundeId }, //the inner selector, the primary key in Kunde, this will match x.KundenNr == y.KundenId
                (x,y) => new { BelegNr = x.BelegId , BelegDatum = x.BelegDatum, Name = y.Name .....}); //here you select the columns(fields) in each table, and construct the new anonymous object with the fields that you need in each table
```

the other problem was: 
I need to change this:

```
foreach (var param in parameters)
    {
        if (param.Key.Equals("BelegId"))
        {
            var belegId = Convert.ToInt32(param.Value);
            query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.BelegId == belegId);
        }

        if (param.Key == "Name")
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Name.Contains(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("Datum"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Datum.Equals(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("KundenNr"))
        {
            var kundenNr = Convert.ToInt32(param.Value);
            query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.KundenNr == kundenNr);
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("Land"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Land.ZweiBuchstabenIsoCode.Contains(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("PLZ"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Plz.Contains(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("Ort"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Kunde.Ort.Contains(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("Erfasser"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.ErfasstVonUsername.Contains(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("Kommission"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.KopfKommission.Contains(param.Value));
        }

        if (param.Key.Equals("ErstePosition"))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => x.Beleg.ErsteRechnungsPosition.Contains(param.Value));
        }
    }
```

into this:

```
if (parameters.ContainsKey("BelegId"))
                {
                    var belegId = Convert.ToInt32(parameters["BelegId"]);
                    query = query.Where(x => x.BelegId == belegId);
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("Name"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["Name"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("Datum"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["Name"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.BelegDatum.Equals(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("KundenNr"))
                {
                    var kundenNr = Convert.ToInt32(parameters["KundenNr"]);
                    query = query.Where(x => x.KundenNr == kundenNr);
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("Land"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["Land"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Land.ZweiBuchstabenIsoCode.Contains(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("PLZ"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["PLZ"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Plz.Contains(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("Ort"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["Ort"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Ort.Contains(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("Erfasser"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["Erfasser"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.ErfasstVonUsername.Contains(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("Kommission"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["Kommission"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.KopfKommission.Contains(tmp));
                }

                if (parameters.ContainsKey("ErstePosition"))
                {
                    var tmp = parameters["ErstePosition"];
                    query = query.Where(x => x.ErsteRechnungsPosition.Contains(tmp));
                }
```

I guess the problem is the foreach loop. 
The loop is executing the query twice, in the second code block the query is executed at the end of the function.